# Stop other music apps using onAudioFocusChange

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I'm trying to create a radio application that plays music in the background but I have a problem with other music app ,when my app and other music application are playing music at the same time,for that i tried to use `AudioFocus` to resolve this problem ,my code below which is working but in one direction

**Issue**

- (Music app e.g Google Play Music ) playing music when i run my app at first time ,Google play Music stop playing music and my app playing music ( **Works** )
- My app playing music in background and when i open Google Play Music my app stop playing music and Google Play Music play music (**Works**)
- Pause playing music from Google Play Music to allow my app to resume/start playing music again (**not working**)
- Pause playing music from my app to allow Google Play Music playing music again  (**not working**)

My code :

```
 private AudioManager mAudioManager;
    boolean mAudioFocusGranted = false;
    private AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener mOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
            switch (focusChange) {
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    MusicButton.setChecked(false);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT:
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    MusicButton.setChecked(false);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK:
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    MusicButton.setChecked(false);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    MusicButton.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    MusicButton.setChecked(true);
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.2f,0.2f);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
SuppressLint({"CommitPrefEdits", "Assert"})
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MusicButton = findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
        mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            mAudioFocusGranted = true;
        } else if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED) {
            MusicButton.setChecked(true);
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
```

Please someone help me to resolve this problem 
*sorry for my english

Comment: That's just how audio focus works.  Pausing the music in one app does not typically trigger a focus change that will cause another app to resume.  The app has to call abandonAudioFocus() or abandonAudioFocusRequest(audioFocusRequest), which should usually be called in response to stop(), not pause().

Comment: @RobertNekic thanks so much for your comment please can you give me some tips to do what i looking for

Comment: Tapping pause in Google Music is not going to trigger a focus gain to you.  You can't do anything about that.   As I said, audio apps do not typically abandon focus when the user pauses.  If the user pauses Google Music and wants to resume your app, they will manually tap Play in the app itself or via your media notification if it's still visible.

If you want Google Music to resume after you pause, you'll have to abandon the focus yourself by calling abandonAudioFocus after pausing the MediaPlayer.   Although, again, a user does not necessarily expect such behavior from pause.

Comment: Also, your case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK code is lowering the volume but you should set the volume back to normal in your GAIN code.

Comment: @RobertNekic thanks so much for your  answer please can i dispense  `AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK ` ?

Comment: In most cases Android Oreo now handles ducking automatically unless you specifically ask it not to.  For older versions, you will want to keep that code and either lower the volume or simply pause. Then reset the volume or resume in your GAIN code.  It can depend on the type of audio you are playing.  For spoken word, I prefer apps pause playback in response to LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK but if you are playing music, most users prefer the volume lowered instead.

Comment: @RobertNekic please one more question after lower the volume how i can  raise it back to normal in GAIN

Comment: I believe you simply need to call mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);

Answer (score 0):

This is a summary of my comments above, if you want to accept it as an answer:

Pausing the music/audio in one app does not typically trigger a focus change that will cause another app to resume. The app has to call abandonAudioFocus() or abandonAudioFocusRequest(audioFocusRequest), which should usually be called in response to stop(), not pause().

Tapping pause in Google Music is not going to trigger a focus gain to you. You can't do anything about that. If the user pauses Google Music and wants to resume your app, they will manually tap Play in your app or via your media notification if it's still visible.

If you want Google Music to resume after you pause, you'll have to abandon the focus yourself by calling abandonAudioFocus after pausing the MediaPlayer. Although, again, a user does not necessarily expect such behavior from a pause button.

Answer (score 0):

with answer of @Robert Nekic and this Demo of [AndroidAudioFocus](https://github.com/abbassoftware/AndroidAudioFocus) Finally I solved my problem